# Labview how to make a while loop (2) inside a while loop (1) that only executes if boolean is true

Tags: loops, while-loop, labview

I'm trying to program a siglent function generator and make use of its burst mode. I want to use the trigger at the back of the function generator to trigger the burst initiation, then use a while loop to increment the burst delay so that the burst peak slowly moves along the burst wave after triggered. The external trigger is from a 5MHz source and periodic. 
In the code I first initialize the function generator, and put in the necessary parameters for the burst waveform, then I have a button that controls if channel output is enabled or not. I want to only use the "enable output" VI if this button is clicked. So "enable output" VI will disable/enable the output only when the button is clicked. I used an event structure to detect button clicking.

Now the problem is, when the button is pressed (enable output), I need to use a while loop or someway to keep increasing the burst delay and send that to the function generator. I need the burst peak to be right after trigger, and slowly moving towards end of next trigger, when reaches the end it should return to right after the first trigger and repeat, until I stop this part.

What is a standard way of doing this? I've tried case structure as well but I can't seem to get the inside increasing delay loop to stop.

Thanks

[code snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzhi6.png)

Comment: The question is not very clear to me, but in general, the block diagram is in bad style. Event handling can be designed in better way. Can you please simplify the problem?

Comment: Would you add a plot of (1) the signal you're generating; of (2) the version of the signal with burst delay; and of (3) how the 5 MHz trigger aligns with the signal? I want to visualize what the uninterrupted output waveform would be. For example, right now my best guess is: a signal is repeated with 0 V segments between each repetition; each repetition is started from the external trigger; each repetition has more and more delay from its start and the external trigger.

Comment: Do you just need a shift register on a single While Loop that changes the burst delay and a second shift register that chooses which of two states to execute? That would solve the two loops issue, if I'm reading your description right.

Answer (score 2):

I give you an example.

Front panel

[image]

Block diagram

[image]

With this code, I can run and stop random number loop.

But, I am not sure this example is what you want.